# Is there any way I can change my code to make python run it faster?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I created a function `max_points` that compares two argument strings and returns a certain value in relation to a separately given criterion that involves summing up the values `ga`, `la`, `ldif`, and `lgap`.  It also returns the list of combinations of the strings that reach this certain value. The strings `s` and `t` go through a process of running through their respective anagrams with up to `n` gaps (in this case, the gap is '_'). Here in an example of what the function should return:

```
In [3]: max_points('AT_', 'A_T', 2, 5, 1, 0, 2)
Out[3]: (16, [['_A_T_', '_A_T_'], 
              ['A__T_', 'A__T_'], 
              ['A_T__', 'A_T__']])
```

The code I have right now is this:

```
def max_points(s, t, ga, la, ldif, lgap, n = 1):

lst_s=generate_n_gaps(s, n)
lst_t=generate_n_gaps(t, n)
point_max=-9999
for i in lst_s:
    for j in lst_t:
        if len(i)==len(j):
            point=pointage(i, j, ga, la, ldif, lgap)
        if point>=point_max:
            point_max=point
ultimate=[]           
for i in lst_s:
    for j in lst_t:
        if len(i)==len(j) and pointage(i, j, ga, la, ldif, lgap)==point_max:
            specific=[]
            specific.append(i)
            specific.append(j)
            ultimate.append(specific)
            
            
return point_max, ultimate
```

The other functions, `generate_n_gaps` and `pointage` (not shown) work as follows:
`generate_n_gaps`: Returns a list of all the combinations of the argument strings with up to `n` gaps.
`pointage`: Compares only the two argument strings `s` and `t` (not all their combinations) and returns an integer value that goes through the same criterion as the `max_points` function.

You can see that, if the length of the argument strings `s` and `t` are larger than 4 or 5 and if `n` is larger than 2, then the function ends up outputting quite a large amount of lists.  I suspect that is why it takes longer than 2 or 3 seconds for some inputs.  Is there any way I can make my code for this specific function faster (<1 sec of runtime)? Or might the problem lie on the other non-specified functions used?

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing, but look into libraries like numpy and statspy. They'll make use of parallel hardware if possible.

Comment: yeah, I should probably specify what the function is supposed to do, but didn't want to clutter up the post too much, I'll include it now

Answer (score 0):

One obvious issue here is that you're looping through all i,j combinations twice: once to calculate the maximum value, and then a second time to return all (i,j) combinations that achieve this maximum.

It would probably be more efficient to do this in a single pass. Something like:

```
point_max=-9999
# or better yet, -math.inf
ultimate=[]
for i in lst_s:
    for j in lst_t:
        if len(i)==len(j):
            point=pointage(i, j, ga, la, ldif, lgap)
        if point>point_max:
            point_max=point
            ultimate=[]
        if point==point_max:
            specific=[]
            specific.append(i)
            specific.append(j)
            ultimate.append(specific)
```

This should approximately halve your run-time.

If i and j have many different possible lengths, you might also be able to achieve savings by blocking up the comparisons. Instead of simply looping through lst_s and lst_t, split these lists up by length (use a dict structure keyed by length, with each value being the subset of lst_s or lst_t having that length). Then iterate through all possible lengths, checking *only* the s- and t-values of that length against one another. This is a bit more work to set up, but may be useful depending on how many comparisons it saves you.

You haven't included the code for max_points but I would be looking hard at that to see if there are any possible savings there; you're going to be calling it a lot, so you want to make it as efficient as possible.

More advanced options include parallelisation, and making use of specific information about the "score" function to do more precise blocking of your score calls. But try the simple stuff first and see if that does the job.

Comment: I had thought of this, but unfortunately it doesn't work, since by doing this, it does not return ALL of the pairs of strings that reach the wanted 'point_max'

Comment: Aaaa I see, I still am not really comfortable with the methods you pointed out, but will definitely be taking a look into them, thank you!

Comment: @NicholasBoscolo Are you sure it doesn't return all the pairs? The first time we reach a maximal pair, ultimate gets cleared (because point will be greater than the old value of point_max), and after that, every maximal pair including that first one should be added to ultimate without clearing the previously discovered pairs.

Comment: I double checked right now, it indeed does not return all of the pairs, although through the code you've written it looks like it should be returning all of them, quite strange.

Comment: @NicholasBoscolo I had a small bug, should work now. (Thanks Kelly!)